# Unittesting Azure System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json'

Tags: c#, azure

I have a library that retrieves secrets from Azure. I can use it without a problem from a console app, but when I use it from unittest, I get an error:

> Test method UnitTests.UnitTest1.TestCredentials threw exception:
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> at Common.Credentials.GetDbConnStr(String databaseName)    at UnitTests.UnitTest1.TestCredentials()

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text.Json;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace Common
{
    public class Credentials
    {
        public static string GetDbConnStr(string databaseName)
        {
            string keyVaultUrl = "https://cat.vault.azure.net/";
            Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving credentials for {databaseName}");
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var res = client.GetSecret("conn");
            return res.Value.Value.ToString() + $"Database={databaseName}";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the test:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Common;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCredentials()
        {
            string conn_str = Credentials.GetDbConnStr("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I can see System.Text.Json.dll in the bin/Debug folder of the test project.

Comment: Check your versions of Function runtime, .NET, etc. - refer this Github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1898)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran) who posted [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046328/unittesting-azure-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/71052505#comment125601193_71046328)

> Check your versions of Function runtime, .NET, etc. - refer this Github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1898)

I upgraded `System.Text.Json` to version 6.0.2 as suggested in the issue and the problem went away.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue at my end by installing the nuget package with latest version of **System.Text.Json**